# É possível criar um MAP<> dentro de outro MAP<>?

Tags: java

É possível criar um `MAP<>` dentro de outro `MAP<>`?
tipo este código:

```
private Map<String, Map<String,Object>>  mapTESTE = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
```

***Se sim:***

Como insiro valores no segundo MAP<>?

é uma boa pratica?

preciso de algo deste género porque tanto a chave do primeiro MAP<> como a chave do segundo não devem ser repetidas.

Outras maneiras de implementar algo deste género são bem vindas

**_____****edit****_____**

Preciso de atualizar dados de 5 em 5 minutos

a estrutura é algo deste género:
//

id1:

```
     nº do produto1 || dados do produto1

     nº do produto2 || dados do produto2
             .......
     nº do produtoX || dados do produtoX
```

id2:

```
     nº do produto1 || dados do produto1

     nº do produto2 || dados do produto2
             .......
     nº do produtoX || dados do produtoX
```

id3:

```
     nº do produto1 || dados do produto1

     nº do produto2 || dados do produto2
             .......
     nº do produtoX || dados do produtoX
```

o id's nao se repetem, isto é quando chega um igual tenho de atualizar os valores que está dentro do MAP<>

e os números do produto também não se podem repetir

Basicamente os valores que sofrem mais atualizações é os dados do produto.

*Possivelmente esta não é a melhor maneira de fazer isto, mas confesso que gosto especialmente de usar MAP por causa de automaticamente atualizaram os valores pelo mais recente e não deixam repetir as chaves*

Comment: "tanto a chave do primeiro MAP como a chave do segundo não devem ser repetidas" Você quer dizer, cada par não pode se repetir, certo? Ex.: `(a,c) (a,d) (b,c) (b,d)` pode? E `(a, b) (b, a)` pode? Ou mesmo `(a, a)`. Se possível, esclareça melhor qual é o seu problema de fato, e não apenas sua tentativa de solução (i.e. contextualize).

Comment: De acordo com sua edição, *me parece* que um map de maps como você propôs é uma boa alternativa sim. Os ids não se repetem no map principal, e os nºs dos produtos não se repetem em cada sub-map. Os dados dos produtos, esses são independentes de id pra id, certo? Ex.: `(id1,produto1,dadoX) (id2,produto1,dadoY)` De modo que se você precisa atualizar o `id1`, vai ficar `(id1,produto1,dadoZ) (id2,produto1,dadoY)` - os demais dados referentes ao mesmo produto não mudam. Confere?

Comment: Sim exatamente isso, os dados do produto estão completamente relacionados com o nº do produto e o nº do produto está completamente relacionado com o  id, nao existe maneira desses números de se repetirem quando se repetem é porque o os dados do produto mudaram então tenho de percorrer e basta adicionar um "dados novo" que como é um MAP automaticamente substitui. Na tua opinião o meu pensamento está correto?

Comment: Sim, especialmente como "o nº do produto está completamente relacionado com o id", assim não há conflito. Creio que esteja tudo correto então.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Para acessar o segundo `Map`, simplesmente obtenha uma referência para ele (usando a primeira chave):

```
Map<String,Object> interno = new HashMap<String,Object>()
mapTESTE.put(primeiraChave, interno);
interno.put(segundaChave, object);

...

// Obtém o valor
Object object = mapTESTE.get(primeiraChave).get(segundaChave);

// Atualiza o valor
mapTESTE.get(primeiraChave).put(segundaChave, novoValor);

// Atualiza a segunda chave
Object valor = mapTESTE.get(primeiraChave).remove(segundaChave);
mapTESTE.get(primeiraChave).put(novaChave, valor);

// Atualiza a primeira chave (para todos os valores da segunda)
Map<String,Object> interno = mapTESTE.remove(primeiraChave);
mapTESTE.put(novaChave, interno);
```

Se essa é ou não a melhor opção depende se existe ou não uma hierarquia entre as chaves. Como o exemplo acima mostrou, mexer na primeira chave afeta todos os valores independente da segunda chave. Às vezes, isso é exatamente o que você quer, mas em outras situações pode não ser.

Se as chaves são independentes, então é preferível criar um objeto compondo as duas chaves:

```
class Chaves {
    String primeira;
    String segunda;
    // Implementar equals e hashCode (importante)
}
```

E usar esse objeto como chave do seu map:

```
Map<Chaves,Object> mapTESTE
```

Inclusive você pode criar maps auxiliares para pesquisar por uma ou outra chave:

```
Map<String,Chaves> buscaPorPrimeiraChave;
Map<String,Chaves> buscaPorSegundaChave;
```

(Talvez exista alguma classe em Java que sirva para isso, mas se existe não me recordo; arrays não são uma opção, pois sua operação de igualdade não leva em consideração o conteúdo desse array - só se é ou não o mesmo objeto)

Comment: Mas se o método `CompareTo` for sobrescrito, não é possível usar um array mesmo? implementando o método conforme for necessário, verificando as duas chaves do objeto

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Faz anos que não trabalho com Java, então não me recordo: você se refere ao `TreeMap`? O `HashMap` não usa comparadores, somente a função `hashCode` das suas chaves. E, se me lembro bem, arrays comparam usando a identidade do objeto somente. Ex.: `int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2 }; int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2 };` Nesse caso, `a == b` é `false`, pois são objetos diferentes. Me corrija se eu estiver enganado.

Comment: Corrigindo, eu quis dizer o método `Equals` Também não recordo muito de Java pois não utilizo no dia-a-dia, mas lembro de que na minha graduação eu fiz uma implementação de uma `List<T>` onde eu sobrescrevi o método `Equals` e consegui implementar uma regra nele que fazia a comparação com base em 4 atributos do objeto.

Answer (score 4):

**É possível sim**, você inseri normalmente assim:

```java
Map<String, Map<String,Object>> mapTESTE = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
Map<String, Object> segundoMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
segundoMap.put("key1.1", "value1.1");
mapTESTE.put("key1", segundoMap);
```

Ou assim em um `loop`:

```java
Map<String, Map<String,Object>> mapTESTE = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
int size1 = 3;
int size2 = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
    Map<String, Object> segundoMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        // key nesse formato: key-i-j, onde 'i' é o indice do primeiro map e 'j' é o indice do segundo map
        segundoMap.put("key-" + i + " - "+ j, "value-" + i + " - "+ j);
    }
    // key nesse formato: key-i, onde 'i' é o indice do primeiro map
    mapTESTE.put("key-" + i, segundoMap);
}
```

**Se é uma boa pratica?**

Sim é uma boa forma de manter coleções com chaves únicas, só deve ser analisado se há a necessidade de se manter um coleção nessa estrutura ou é possível manter uma coleção mais simples como `ArrayList<T>`. No seu caso você citou a necessidade de as duas chaves serem unicas, então acredito que essa é forma correta.

Como você citou em sua edição, para editar o conteúdo do sub Map faça algo assim:

```java
mapTESTE.get("key1").put("key1.1", "novo valor");
```

> Não sei se é bem isso que você pretende, mas de forma simples é assim que se faz.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível.

Para colocar um valor no mapa que está dentro do primeiro mapa, faça assim:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> teste = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
teste.put("primeiro", new HashMap<String, String>());
teste.get("primeiro").put("primeiro chave do sub map", "primeiro valor do sub map");
```

Se isso é uma boa prática ou não é difícil de dizer, depende do que procura pode ser sim uma boa solução. Uma alternativa seria fazer criando uma classe que contenha dois atributos para ser usado como o valor do seu primeiro mapa.

```
class MeuMapa {
    private Set<String> primeiro;
    private String segundo;
    public MeuMapa(Set<String> primeiro, String segundo) {
        this.primeiro = primeiro;
        this.segundo = segundo;
    }
    public Set<String> getPrimeiro() { return primeiro; }
    public void setPrimeiro(Set<String> primeiro) { this.primeiro = primeiro; }
    public String getSegundo() { return segundo; }
    public void setSegundo(String segundo) { this.segundo = segundo; }
    //implemente o hashCode() e o equals() aqui
    //o próprio eclipse faz isso de forma automática
}
```

Note que o primeiro atributo é um Set, que não permite duplicados, logo, como disse que nem o primeiro valor do seu map, nem o primeiro valor do seu segundo map podem ser repetidos acredito que isso atenda.

Para usá-lo ficaria assim:

```
Map<String, MeuMapa> mapa = new HashMap<>();
MeuMapa meuMapa = new MeuMapa(new HashSet<String>(), "segundo");
mapa.put("primeiro", meuMapa);
```

Mas tudo depende de qual é a sua necessidade, você pode ir por um caminho ou por outro, ambos podem ser considerados "certos".